# iPhone - ampersand, what ampersand?

Tags: iphone, ios

I see this line on one of Apple samples...

```
if (&ADBannerContentSizeIdentifierPortrait != nil)
```

what is exactly this ampersand doing that?

thanks

Comment: what kind of object `ADBannerContentSizeIdentifierPortrait` is?

Comment: good question. It is a variable from iAd Framework.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The ampersand in C and languages that "derive" from it (like C++ and Objective-C) returns the *address* of a variable (instead of the *content*).

In this case, what's happening is this: the variable `ADBannerContentSizeIdentifierPortrait` is a weakly linked variable. This means, at runtime it may be missing (this is the case in older OS versions). Now, if the variable *does* exist the ampersand returns an address. If the OS does not yet have this variable, the ampersand returns `nil`.

So in short: the expression checks whether the OS is already providing the variable `ADBannerContentSizeIdentifierPortrait`. According do [the documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/IOS/#documentation/UserExperience/Reference/ADBannerView_Ref/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009562-CH1-SW4) this variable exists since iOS 4.2, so the body of the `if` expression is only executed on iOS >= 4.2.

Comment: After posting I started suspecting that something like that would be the reason, but your answer answered more than I was imagining. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

The ampersand depicts a reference to the data. The ADBannerContentSizeIdentifierPortrait is a simple enumerated value, and therefore cannot be nil itself, but it's reference can be. Please add more code if you require a more thorough answer.

Comment: `ADBannerContentSizeIdentifierPortrait` is not a "enumerated value", it's a NSString constant.

Comment: Correct, my mistake - although the main idea is still valid.